# Visualizing a homotopy pull back

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, visualization

I am currently taking a course in algebraic topology, which also covers a lot of category theory. My question is pretty straightforward:

> How do you visualize the (homotopy) pull back of a diagram $B\to
>  C\leftarrow A$ ?

In class the professor usually just kind of says "Well if you think about it you get....".  I have figured out that for a (homotopy) push out you want to glue the two spaces together along their common points but the description of the pullback has eluded me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics.SE! Are the notes for your course publicly availabel online?

Comment: The notes are not online, but we are using the book "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory" by Jeffery Strom if that helps.

Comment: Modern...yet Classical !?! sounds cool. Thank you

Comment: It is a new book, printed in 2011.  Dr.Strom is a professor at my school, Western Michigan University, which is why we are using it over more standard books (e.g. Hatcher's).  It has it's merits, plenty of good illustrations and examples, but the big downfall is that there are no formal proofs, only (somewhat) guided exercises which walk you through the steps that you need to take to prove the theorems.  This can be a bit frustrating for a new student who is struggling with the concepts since I have no reference to old proofs to try to apply to new ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard construction of the homotopy pullback involves the total path space $C^I$ (i.e. the space of all continuous maps $I \to C$, with the appropriate topology). More precisely, if $f : A \to C$ and $g : B \to C$ are the given maps, then:
$$A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B = \{ (a, p, b) \in A \times C^I \times B : p(0) = f(a), p(1) = g(b) \}$$

The path space $C^I$ is rather difficult to visualise, as it is generally infinite dimensional. But the idea should be clear enough: a point of $A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B$ is a point in $A$ and a point in $B$ together with a path in $C$ connecting the images of those two points.

Notice that there is a canonical map $A \times_C B \to A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B$. Under good conditions, this is a homotopy equivalence. Indeed, if $g : B \to C$ is a Hurewicz fibration, then the homotopy extension/lifting property gives us a map $(A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B) \times I \to B$ extending the canonical map $(A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B) \times \{ 1 \} \to B$ and lifting the canonical map $(A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B) \times I \to C$; restricting to $(A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B) \times \{ 0 \} \to B$ we then get a commutative square
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
(A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B)  & \rightarrow & B \\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow \\
A & \rightarrow & C 
\end{array}$$
and hence a map $A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B \to A \times_C B$ that is left inverse to the canonical map $A \times_C B \to A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B$; in fact, this map $A \times^\mathrm{h}_C B \to A \times_C B$ is also a homotopy right inverse. Thus, when $g : B \to C$ is a Hurewicz fibration, the homotopy pullback coincides with the ordinary pullback (up to homotopy equivalence).

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks