# What does "cst" stand for in algebraic topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a question on notation present in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454921/268197).

> Define $E_p = \{ (y, \gamma) \in E \times B^{[0,1]} \mid p(y) = \gamma(0) \}$. There's a map (in fact a fibration) $q : E_p \to B$, $(y,\gamma) \mapsto \gamma(1)$, and the homotopy fiber is the fiber $F_p = q^{-1}(b_0)$. The inclusion $$i : F = p^{-1}(b_0) \to F_p$$ is given by $i(y) = (y, \mathrm{cst}_{b_0})$.

My question is, what does the cst stand for here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function constant to $b_0$

Comment: I can confirm that this is what I had in mind when I wrote the post.