# Homotopy fiber of a bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a locally trivial bundle with fiber $F$ where $X,Y$ are compact CW-complexes (or even smooth manifolds).

**Is it true that $F$ is homotopically equivalent the homotopy fiber of $f$?**

A reference would be helpful.

Sorry if this question is not of the research level.

Comment: Is "homotopic fiber of $f$" standard language in some textbook, or is that a mistake, or more like sloppiness?

Comment: @RyanBudney: Thanks, that was sloppiness. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was basically already asked on Stackexchange,
see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842286/showing-that-a-homotopy-fiber-of-a-fibration-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-the-fiber) for an answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) is a Serre fibration (this is a standard fact, for example, [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf), prop. 4.48). Therefore, its fiber over any point is its homotopy fiber.

Comment: Your last sentence is not clear to me. By the homotopy fiber I mean the fiber of the pathspace construction $X_f\to Y$ (see Hatcher's book, discussion before Prop. 4.64). The homotopy fiber over a point $y_0\in Y$  is equal to the set of pairs $(x,\gamma)$ where $x\in X$ and $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to Y$ is a continuous map such that $\gamma(0)=f(x)$. In the situation of my post I do not see why the fiber $F$ is homotopically equivalent to the homotopy fiber.

Comment: It's a theorem that the ordinary fibres and homotopy fibres of fibrations are homotopy equivalent. The answer using "is" reflects the attitude of working up to homotopy.

Comment: @DavidRoberts that is not a theorem. The fibers of a Serre fibration (over points in the same path component) are only weakly homotopy equivalent. If this is what is meant then it is not unreasonable to ask for it to be stated clearly.

Comment: While Hatcher's proof is fine, it's not emphasized enough that there are some really beautiful proofs.  For example, put a connection on your fiber bundle and use the holonomy construction.  This gives you a very appealing description of fiber bundles as Serre fibrations.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: If this is a theorem, why not to state it precisely and give a reference. (In fact, in another answer below there is a link to good answer.) Also I do not quite understand why the question was downvoted.

Comment: @Tyrone note the ambiguity in "fibration" - is it a Serre fibration or a Hurewicz fibration? Perhaps nowadays the default is Serre, but it used to be the other way. In the application, a fibre bundle over a CW complex, then generically it's just a Serre fibration, but since the base is CW, then it is paracompact Hausdorff, hence the fibre bundle is numerable, hence it is a Hurewicz fibration. I also toyed with writing "in the homotopy category", but was on mobile and being a bit too quick when writing that comment. The important part is the second sentence.